# Javascript Element opening and closing problem

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    var a = document.querySelector('.secenek-1');
    var b = document.querySelector('.secenek-1-kismi');
    
    a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault
        b.classList.contains("showing") ? b.classList.remove("showing") : b.classList.add("showing");
    })
    var c = document.querySelector('.secenek-2');
    var d = document.querySelector('.secenek-2-kismi');
    
    c.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    
        e.preventDefault
        d.classList.contains("showing") ? d.classList.remove("showing") : d.classList.add("showing");
    })
    var e = document.querySelector('.secenek-3');
    var f = document.querySelector('.secenek-3-kismi');
    e.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault
        f.classList.contains("showing") ? f.classList.remove("showing") : f.classList.add("showing");
    })
</script>
```

I want that if `.secenek-1-kismi` div is open, if i clicked `secenek-2`, `.secenek-1-kismi` will close and `.secenek-2-kismi` will open

Comment: What happens with current code? Please add more description. If you have error messages please include them. How is PHP related? Likely relevant HTML should be added to question as well.

Comment: It's best to provide a [mre]. That would include some HTML in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ill fix it.

```js
    <script>
         
        function js_div_show(value) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                if (value == i) { 
                    var yakalanan = document.getElementById('div_show_' + i);
                    yakalanan.style.display = "block"; 
                } else {
                    var yakalanmayan = document.getElementById('div_show_' + i);
                    yakalanmayan.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        } 
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="col-xs-3 menu-root-item" onclick="js_div_show(1);">
 <img>
<h2></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behavior you described, you'll need to modify the event listeners. You can add conditional checks to close any open sections before opening the clicked section. Here's the updated code:

```
<script>
    var a = document.querySelector('.secenek-1');
    var b = document.querySelector('.secenek-1-kismi');
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!b.classList.contains("showing")) {
            // Close other sections if open
            var openSections = document.querySelectorAll('.showing');
            openSections.forEach(function(section) {
                section.classList.remove("showing");
            });

            b.classList.add("showing");
        } else {
            b.classList.remove("showing");
        }
    });

    var c = document.querySelector('.secenek-2');
    var d = document.querySelector('.secenek-2-kismi');
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!d.classList.contains("showing")) {
            // Close other sections if open
            var openSections = document.querySelectorAll('.showing');
            openSections.forEach(function(section) {
                section.classList.remove("showing");
            });

            d.classList.add("showing");
        } else {
            d.classList.remove("showing");
        }
    });

    var e = document.querySelector('.secenek-3');
    var f = document.querySelector('.secenek-3-kismi');
    e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!f.classList.contains("showing")) {
            // Close other sections if open
            var openSections = document.querySelectorAll('.showing');
            openSections.forEach(function(section) {
                section.classList.remove("showing");
            });

            f.classList.add("showing");
        } else {
            f.classList.remove("showing");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work.
secenek-1 stays on all the time.